# Multiple Ajax calls gets stalled for sometime in random cases

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I have more than 10 AJAX calls on one page expect master page calls. In my `local env.` all ajax requests are working fine but the problem is on `prod env.` randomly some ajax calls get blocked and go to pending(stalled) for some time and after that, it completes requests and sometimes it takes more than 4 minutes to complete a request.

This happens at random times and have not the idea what could be the problem.

The code I use is simple as this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://...',
    cache: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(jsondata),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    async: true,
    success: function(data){ //code },
    error: function(xmlHttpRequest) { //errorhandler }
});
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: C#? How is C# related to your question?

Comment: Could it be a (concurrency?) problem in your C# code?

Comment: thank you @oerkelens for taking time to look into this issue. As you said, there doesn't seem to be a problem in the code. It actually works well in local as well as in QA env. but randomly stucks in production.

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see more code, but sending 10 concurrent requests can lead to problems. I seen firewalls block requests, web-servers refuse to answer etc. You could try sending requests as promises and force requests to a sequential execution (or nest them :) ). See if that works.